# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC Render string from action in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I try to display a string from Action in a View. This sounds like a very simple and easy task, but I don't get it how to do this.

My async Action returns Content Result:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayName(string key)
{
    // Retrieves the requested culture
    var rqf = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    // Culture contains the information of the requested culture
    var culture = rqf.RequestCulture.Culture;

    return Content(await Task.FromResult(_displayProvider.GetDisplayName(key, culture.Name)));
}
```

My View is very simple html:

```
@model List<MyModel>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable">
    <thead class="table-head-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                Actions
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <partial name="_EditDetailButton" model="@item.Id" />
                    <partial name="_DeleteButton" model="@item" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead of `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Id)` I want to Display a user-defined value. The user-defined value is returned from the Action.

I tried `@Url.Action("DisplayName", "DisplayName", new { key = "MyModel.Id" })` but this is rendering an Url.

I tried `Html.RenderAction("DisplayName", "DisplayName", new { key = "LastName" })` but RenderAction does not exist in ASP.NET Core 5.

I could call a static Class e. g. `DisplayNameProvider.GetDisplayName("MyModel.Id", ???)` but i dont know how to get the choosen culture to pass it to the method.

How do I get this working? I am also not familiar with components in ASP.NET Core.

Or is there a completely different solution for displaying strings, which the user has defined and save to the database? The `DisplayNameProvider` is retrieving the strings from database and handles caching.

UPDATE:
The Goal is to store and change displaynames for properties in the database. The user can change the displaynames. In my example the user wants a different displayname for the column header. I cannot use resource files as these are static and cannot be changed during runtime.

This is my DisplayNameProvider.GetDisplayName Method:

```
public string GetDisplayName(string ressourceKey, string language)
{
    var ressources = GetCached(language);

    var item = ressources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ResourceKey == ressourceKey);
    
    return item.Text;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Siemens,What do you mean for `Display a user-defined value.`?Your shared view seems no to be related to your shared action,or maybe you need share what is your `_displayProvider.GetDisplayName()` method.

Comment: Hi @Rena, the user is able to change the value of the label in the database. the label has a key (e.g. `MyModel.Id`) in the database. I want to display/render/show this value in the view. `_displayProvider.GetDisplayName()` Is only returning the value for the key from the database.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Siemens,but `@Html.DisplayNameFor` is used to display the key name not display the value.

Comment: Hi @Rena, thats why i want to replace `@Html.DisplayNameFor` with my own action to display not the Displayname but the value from the database. The value from the database is a value which the user needed as the column header text. The value is like a displayname which the user wants to display as the column header.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Siemens,why not using `@Html.DisplayFor`?

Comment: Hi @Rena, because `@Html.DisplayFor` renders the value of MyModel.Id instead of a user-defined displayname of the MyModel.Id Property which the user can change.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Siemens,So please share what is `_displayProvider.GetDisplayName()` detailed code.

Comment: @Rena, The Goal is to store and change displaynames for properties in the database. How can i put a string returned from an action in my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a string localizer, which returns the desired value for my properties.

Now i can use displaynamefor and it shows the value of the language. E.g.:

`@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MyProperty)`